# Regex for people count

Tags: php, regex

I'm sending SMS to request count.

> Enter the count in this format: **Mx Fx Cx** where *x* is the number.

Possible values:

- m0 f0 c0
- m 0 f 0 c 0
- M0 F0 C0
- M 0 F 0 C 0
- Mxxx0 Fxxx0 Cxxx0
- Mxxx 0 Fxxx 0 Cxxx 0

Validation:

1. Ignore case
2. Ignore spaces
3. Ignore spelling
4. Ignore order or M, F and C.
5. At least one (M, F or C) is required.

Its a fairly complex regex, so I'm not sure how go about it. This is what I have, but it obviously matches just one case:

```
^([Mm]\d{1} [Ff]?\d{1} [Cc]?\d{1})$
```

---

**Solution**:

```
$pattern = "/^([MmCcFf]\D*\d{1}\s*){1,3}$/";
$message = "m 3 f 2 c 9";
preg_match($pattern, $message, $matches);
if ($matches) {
    $res = preg_match_all("/(\D+)(\d+)/", $matches[0], $values);
    echo print_r($values[2],1);
}
```

Comment: I think you know that Stack Overflow isn't a free code writing service. Start with something and show where you got stuck.

Comment: Man. What did you try?

Comment: what could `xxx` be?

Comment: @Thomas Male, Female, Children. There's a chance they would misspell so I want to ignore everything after the first letter.

Comment: But is it numbers or letters or anything? If it can be M, F or C you have a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I've got this (may be not the simplest for now):

```
^([MmCcFf]\D*\d{1}\s*){1,3}$
```

See [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nD2zV1/2)

---

A bit of explaination as asked by [Rizier123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3933332/rizier123):

- `^` means the start of the line;
- `[MmCcFf]` is *one* of the letter inside the group;
- `\D` is any non-digit, followed by `*` it means from 0 to infinity;
- `\d` means any digit, followed by `{1}` is means just one time;
- `\s` is any whitespace char, followed by `*` it means from 0 to infinity;
- `([MmCcFf]\D*\d{1}\s*)` is the concat of all above, followed by `{1,3}` it means from one to three times;
- `$` is the end of the line

Comment: Maybe you wan to explain what exactly this regex does, since maybe not every SO user understand that regex right away.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the explanation as well.

Comment: You might want to include a `\s` right before the `^` to allow white spaces before the first group.

Comment: Way better. Because OP probably won't be the only one who will look at your answer. And with an explanation way more people will understand what exactly this regex does and can learn from it / or modify it slightly, since they know what the single parts do/mean.

Comment: Not essential, but just wondering what if I want to extract the values and save them in the DB. Can I use the same regex or have to process further with PHP?

Comment: @3zzy I have not a single clue about that, sorry mate

Comment: @Thomas Figured it. Updated the description with the complete solution.